# Using IF AND operator in MS Excel leads to argument error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to make this formula work by using IF and AND operators in excel. However I keep getting the too many argument error. I have check for the open and closed braces. Can someone correct the formula if there is anything wrong.

#### One-line version

```
=IF(AND(F2>=190, F2<=194),30,0,IF(AND(F2>=196, F2<=200),30,0,IF(AND(F2>=185, F2<=189),20,0,IF(AND(F2>=201, F2<=205),20,0,IF(AND(F2>=175, F2<=184),10,0,IF(AND(F2>=206, F2<=215),10,0, IF(EXACT(F2,Sheet2!$A4),50,0)))))))
```

#### Multi-line version

```
=IF(
    AND(F2>=190, F2<=194),
    30,
    0,
    IF(
        AND(F2>=196, F2<=200),
        30,
        0,
        IF(
            AND(F2>=185, F2<=189),
            20,
            0,
            IF(
                AND(F2>=201, F2<=205),
                20,
                0,
                IF(
                    AND(F2>=175, F2<=184),
                    10,
                    0,
                    IF(
                        AND(F2>=206, F2<=215),
                        10,
                        0,
                        IF(
                            EXACT(F2, Sheet2!$A4),
                            50,
                            0)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: You have too many arguments in your `IF`s  you need to remove all but the last `,0`

Comment: I also do not see `195` that will be `0`

Comment: BTW, a simpler formula: `=CHOOSE(MATCH(F2,{0,175,185,190,195,196,201,206,216}),0,10,20,30,50,30,20,10,0)`

Comment: actually use: `=CHOOSE(MATCH(ABS(195-A1),{0,1,6,11,21}),50,30,20,10,0)`

Comment: That's a really clever use of the CHOOSE function, may I ask what makes the second formula better?

Comment: @IlikeExcelverymuch it is just shorter and more concise with the pattern.

Comment: Would you mind if I edited my answer to include your formula as a third option? It's much better than my solutions.

Comment: Go ahead.  Rule of thumb with me is, if I make it a comment, as long as you mention where you got it you can include it in the answer. @IlikeExcelverymuch

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to say is "If this is between these two numbers, then that, otherwise if this is between these two numbers, then that...."

What you actually said was "If this is between these two numbers, then that, otherwise 0 and **at the same time** if this is between these two numbers, then that...."

Basically you need to either:

1. Replace every instance of ",0," with just "," (like this) `=IF(AND(F2>=190, F2<=194),30,IF(AND(F2>=196, F2<=200),30,IF(AND(F2>=185, F2<=189),20,IF(AND(F2>=201, F2<=205),20,IF(AND(F2>=175, F2<=184),10,IF(AND(F2>=206, F2<=215),10, IF(EXACT(F2,Sheet2!$A4),50,0)))))))`

**or**

2. Break them in to separate IF() functions and add them together (like this) `=IF(AND(F2>=190,F2<=194),30,0)+IF(AND(F2>=196,F2<=200),30,0)+IF(AND(F2>=185,F2<=189),20,0)+IF(AND(F2>=201,F2<=205),20,0)+IF(AND(F2>=175,F2<=184),10,0)+IF(AND(F2>=206,F2<=215),10,0)+IF(EXACT(F2,Sheet2!$A4),50,0)`

**Updated to include the solution made by @Scott Craner**

3. `=CHOOSE(MATCH(ABS(195-F2),{0,1,6,11,21}),50,30,20,10,0)`

Match() returns a number corresponding to where a value occurs in a range (so the 1st is 1, the 2nd is 2, etc.) if that number is not present then it returns largest number that is less than the value, CHOOSE() does the opposite of MATCH(), it finds and returns a value corresponding to a range by looking up where it occurs (if you have a range of {"a","b","c"} and requested the 3rd it would return "C".

ABS() turns negatives into positives and leaves positives unchanged.